# LaTeX VERY compact itemize

Tags: latex

I am trying to build  a very compact itemize with LaTeX, because I want to fit it in a table without whitespace everywhere.

What I need:

- No whitespace before list
- No whitespace after list
- No whitespace between lines
- Less indent before the bulletpoints

I have tried many packages (`paralist`, `mdwlist`, `enumitem`) but non of them can fully do it.

I tried it myself (with the help of `paralist`) and could get rid of everything except the whitespace after the list. This is my current solution:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{ilist}%
  {
    %from parlist package, reduces indent before bulletpoints
    \setdefaultleftmargin{1em}{1em}{}{}{}{} 
    \compress %places itemize into minipage, removing whitespace before
    \begin{itemize}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt} 
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}%
  {\end{itemize}}
```

However, I am unable to get rid of the space after the list. I can do it with a negative `vspace` but this is:

1. Ugly
2. Does not work for tables: The rule after the row in which the list is will still be one line below.

Can anyone tell me how to do it? I have googled so much, but it somehow seems that I am the first human that ever tried to insert an itemize into a table :D

Comment: Also try asking on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: `mdwlist` is a package you might want to look at.

Comment: Something similar came up not too long ago. Does the answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210766/latex-vertical-space-before-and-behind-the-lists) help at all?

Answer (score 135):

To change these settings globally

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
```

(And you can use the `\setenumerate`, `\setdescription` or `\setlist` commands for other types of lists)

Or for just a single list

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
...
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: `\setlist{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}` (instead of `\setitemize...`) to set the same global options for all three kinds of lists (`itemize`, `enumerate` and `description`)

Comment: I think I need `leftmargin=*` as another argument? For "very" compact". :)

Comment: You can add this to you commands:
`\usepackage{enumitem} \newenvironment{compitemize} {\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]}   {\end{itemize}}`

and then use \begin{compitemize} where needed

Comment: `enumitem` conflicts with beamer.  We should use this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5941/changing-left-margin-in-itemize-environment-of-beamer-class

Answer (score 9):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974583/2745116) is not up to date as mentioned in the comments. This is what I used to get a compact list:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{topsep=0pt, leftmargin=*}
```

Then use `\begin{itemize}` as usual to start a list.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and [`shortlst`](http://ctan.org/pkg/shortlst) packages.

Comment: Also [`paralist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paralist) and in particular the `compactitem` list style.

Comment: can you tell me how? I already experimented with enumitem but didn't make it. A working snipped would be very helpful, not only for me but others having this problem.

Comment: @gex: see @Ken Bloom's answer for `enumitem.` For `shortlst`, RTM.  And I second the recommendation for the [TeX SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This solution was provided in a comment by @damien-pollet but every time I come back here to find it again, I always have a hard time finding it because it is a comment, so I am putting it as answer for the benefit of my future-self who will be looking for this answer again.

The `compactitem` environment of the [paralist](http://ctan.org/pkg/paralist) package works wonders:

```
\usepackage{paralist}
...
\begin{compactitem}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{compactitem}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the desired layout with the `savetrees` package (caveat: this will also compactify the rest of your document)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{savetrees}

\begin{document}
text
\begin{itemize}
\item No whitespace before list
\item No whitespace after list
\item No whitespace between lines
\item Less indent before the bulletpoints
\end{itemize}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\bbb}[1]{\indent$\bullet$ #1\\}
```

In the document:

```
\bbb{hello world}
```

Comment: You cannot make nested lists with this.